# Azure SQL - what would be the impact while enabling the Failover?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I have an Azure SQL in WEST US and I want to setup the failover grop with EAST US.

Would there be any impact on the primary SQL server during the Geo-Replication is being enabled?

Comment: Per my experience, there isn't only if the primary database has  accidents. We can't feel it. It most like data sync or backup. When something error happened, we can use Geo-replication instead.

Comment: Hi, If my answer is helpful for you, can you please accept it as answer? This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my experience, we can not say there isn't any impact absolutely when the Geo-Replication is being enabled,  only if the primary database has accidents.

In other words, when We configure the Geo-Replication, it's more like data sync or backup. We can't feel that because Azure does the everything at backend for us. When something error happened, we can use Geo-replication immediately instead.

HTH.